# 3D Rotation about globalm axis

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, rotation, translation

i am trying to rotate an Object in 3D around the global axis and i have the Problem, that it doesn't rotate around the origin. 
**Tried the following**

```
        float3 middle = //calculated the center of the cuboit
        mymesh.setTransform(mymesh.getTransform()
        * Matrix::createTranslation(middle)
        * Matrix::createRotationY(-time * speed)
        * Matrix::createTranslation(middle).invert());
```

This is working perfectly fine for **rotation around the local axis**.
If i rotate it around the y-axis only everything is fine. If i rotate it around the x-axis, then the rotation around the y-axis is local and it doesn't rotate the Object globaly anymore.

I have read, that it does matter at wich side of my rotation matrix i multiply my matrix representing the 3D Object. 
If i want it to rotate around the local axis, than i multiply it to the left side.

```
Result = M * rotation
```

Result is the Matrix M after rotation
If i want it to rotate around the Global axis, than i multiply it on the right side:

```
Result = rotation * M
```

Now this is working expect that the translation doesn't work anymore. It is not rotating around the origin but it feels like it is rotation around the center of an outer Point of the cuboit. 
The calculation i do is:

```
        Matrix m = Matrix::createTranslation(middle)
        * Matrix::createRotationY(-time * speed)
        * Matrix::createTranslation((-1.0)* middle);

        mymesh.setTransform(m * mymesh.getTransform());
```

The more i think about it, the less i understand it. now i am even questioning, why the first implementation with the rotation around the local axis worked.
the variable middle is calculate depending on the size of the cubiot and is representing the center of it.
lets say it would be `p1(1,1,1)`
If i move my Object in 3D like 10 on the z axis, than my Object is somewhere at `p2(0,0,10)`. But if i move the Object about `-p1` back, rotate it and move it back, than my Object is still not at the origin, but it rotates like it is at the origin.

It seems i dont understand something important. How do i rotate around the global axis and rotate it like it is at the origin? why is the first implementation working?

EDIT:
Matrix is a 4x4 Matrix to represent the Mesh and float3 is a point for the x,y,z-coordination system

EDIT2:
OK the solution to the problem seems to be to calculate the transaltion that was made. if i know the Vector for the translation, than i can move the Object back to the origin, rotate it and move it back to where it was.
I tried to keep track of the center of the object by adding to a vector every movement i make, but when i change the Form of the Object, the center ist wrong. 
Is there a way to calculate the translation that was made from the Object?
like if i move it on the x-axis 10 to the right and than rotate it. the center wont change position but taking just the translation from the matrix will return a wrong value.

Comment: What is `Matrix`, what is `float3`?

Comment: Added an edit. its a 4x4 Matrix and float3 is the point for the 3D coordination system

Comment: Do you use a specific library? These aren't standard c++ types.

Comment: jeah i use an engine from a friend to draw at 3D

Comment: So how can we know what the problem actually is?

Comment: i thought its something with the calculation, independent of the engine.